# display same data in the range of 2 row using DataBound in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, databound

I want to display same data in between for a range of 2 dates for C# asp.net using DataBound gridview in asp.net c#

example in the image, i want to display the data in between 21-Nov-2013 until 29-Nov-2013 that all the dates in between have the country name Indonesia.

I used int i = e.Row.RowIndex; to capture the current index whr it is match with the date for 21-Nov-2013, int j = e.Row.RowIndex; for 29-Nov-2013.

```
if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "21-Nov-2013")
{
    int i = e.Row.RowIndex;
    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Indonesia";
}
else if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "29-Nov-2013")
{
    int j = e.Row.RowIndex;
    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Indonesia";
}
else {}

for(i;i<j;i++)
gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text = "Indonesia";
```

[image]

Comment: see my new answer it's working

Answer (score 1):

the date that u writen it's not comparable so,first you should convert your date ("21-Nov-2013") to comparable value. save value of

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text in b instead of "21-Nov-2013".

 string month = "1";
            string b = "21-Nov-2013";
            string day = b.Substring(0, 2);
            switch (b.Substring(3,3))
            {
                case "Jun":
                    month = "1";
                    break;

                case "Feb":
                    month = "2";
                    break;
                    /*other month
                     * 
                     * */
                case "Nov":
                    month = "11";
                    break;

            }
            int date=Convert.ToInt32(day+month+b.Substring(7,4));
//compare (daymonthyear)
            if (date >= 21112013 && date<=21112013)
            {

                int i = e.Row.RowIndex;
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Indonesia";

                  }
```

plz complete switch case for other month

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text >= "21-Nov-2013" && e.Row.Cells[0].Text <= "29-Nov-2013")
{
    int i = e.Row.RowIndex;
    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Indonesia";
}
```

u should use &&(and) in u'r loop.it's true when both side of condition be

Comment: .Text cannot compare with string

Comment: save value of e.Row.Cells[0].Text in string variable